# Any kind of tool to monitor stuck thread in weblogic portal?

Tags: weblogic

Is there any kind of tool that can email notify users when a stuck thread in encounter in the weblogic portal?

Comment: What version of WLP are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can try WLSDM. It notifies and attaches thread dump.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a configurable way of achieving what you want through the Weblogic Admin Console, but this is easy to accomplish through Weblogic scripting.

Please follow this excellent guide on getting the thread dump sent through email as soon as a thread is considered "stuck" by Weblogic: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5582

Also, if you want to take preventive measures against stuck threads, this alternate script might help you detecting threads candidate for being stuck, before they actually stuck. I recommend at least reading the post: http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=5423